# How to have Object Rotate clockwise then counter clockwise AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, rotation, flash-cs6

Hey everyone So I was wondering how this could be accomplished? I have been spending some time on this now and can't seem to figure it out. I know its missing a few variables but don't know really where to start. This is what I have so far in my mcSpear class.

```
private function init():void 
    {
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, SpearLoop);
    }

    private function SpearLoop(e:Event):void 
    {
        this.rotation += 5;

        if (this.rotation >= 180)
        {
            trace("greater than 180");

            this.rotation -= 5;
        }


    }
```

This does rotate the object clockwise then when it reaches the if Statement it just starts twitching and never changes direction. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will block your object in the same position when its rotation is 180°. Why ?

Because every time when `object.rotation >= 180`, you do `object.rotation -= 5` so it's now 175° and the next time you will set it back to 180° with `object.rotation += 5`, so you create an infinite loop. To avoid that, you can use a `Boolean` var, for example, which can indicate the sens of rotation like this :

```
var clockwise:Boolean = true;

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, SpearLoop);

function SpearLoop(e:Event):void 
{
    if(this.rotation >= 180){ 
        clockwise = false;  // activate the counterclockwise sens 
    } else if(this.rotation <= 0){
        clockwise = true;   // activate the clockwise sens  
    }

    if (clockwise){
        this.rotation += 5;
    } else {
        this.rotation -= 5;
    }

}
```

Hope that can help.

Comment: This is perfect and makes way more sense than what I was doing. Thank you so much for your help and the explanationI really appreciate it.